# Conditional Editing of Large TSV in Linux

Tags: linux, awk, terminal, grep

I have many large TSV files that have 6 unnamed columns and around 10 million rows.  I need to apply a change on a row-by-row basis and save as a new TSV.  I am working on **Linux** and have access to awk, gawk, grep.  Ideally the code would reference column numbers in its operators so it functions regardless of row content.  TYIA!

The only changes that need to be made are to Columns 2 & 3, but the change is conditional on the value within Column 6:

```
If the value of column 6 is "+", then:  
New Column 2: [Column 2 Value]  
New Column 3: [Column 2 Value] + 1  
  
If the value of column 6 is "-", then:  
New Column 2: [Column 3 Value] - 1  
New Column 3: [Column 3 Value]
```

**Example TSV Data Structure (no | present in actual data)**

```
| AI     | 828     | 878     | ABC4807:78485:5:79215       | 42 | - |
| AI     | 971     | 1021    | ABC248:78485:5:79215:46065  | 42 | + |
| AI     | 1104    | 1153    | X7481:78485:5:79215:40174   | 35 | - |
| XVDIII | 56939   | 56988   | 9478:78485:5:79215:30872    | 42 | - |
| XVDIII | 56971   | 57020   | 7841S:78485:5:79215:34301   | 42 | - |
| UTXV   | 1043196 | 1043246 | T885189:78485:5:79215:10036 | 42 | + |
| UTXV   | 1043198 | 1043248 | C74581:78485:5:79215:10792  | 42 | - |
| UTXV   | 1043201 | 1043250 | T75S17:78485:5:79215:30204  | 42 | - |
| UTXV   | 1043201 | 1043251 | B784W7:78485:5:79215:42548  | 42 | - |
```

**Desired TSV Output**

```
| AI     | 877     | 878     | ABC4807:78485:5:79215       | 42 | - |
| AI     | 971     | 972     | ABC248:78485:5:79215:46065  | 42 | + |
| AI     | 1152    | 1153    | X7481:78485:5:79215:40174   | 35 | - |
| XVDIII | 56987   | 56988   | 9478:78485:5:79215:30872    | 42 | - |
| XVDIII | 57019   | 57020   | 7841S:78485:5:79215:34301   | 42 | - |
| UTXV   | 1043196 | 1043197 | T885189:78485:5:79215:10036 | 42 | + |
| UTXV   | 1043247 | 1043248 | C74581:78485:5:79215:10792  | 42 | - |
| UTXV   | 1043249 | 1043250 | T75S17:78485:5:79215:30204  | 42 | - |
| UTXV   | 1043250 | 1043251 | B784W7:78485:5:79215:42548  | 42 | - |
```

Comment: That should be fairly straightforward with `awk`; don't you wanna give a try yourself?

Comment: Biologist here with minimal knowledge of coding in Linux.  I don't know how to reference unnamed columns or how to set up a conditional statement.  Sometime I post things that I think will be easy for others that would otherwise take me hours/days.

Comment: Here's a skeleton code for you: `awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"} {if ($6 == "+") {$3 = ...} else {...}; print}' file.tsv`

Comment: I appreciate the effort of @Fravadona to support the asking person in trying to write the script by himself. But besides the basic algorithm the details will overwhelm an absolute newbie in AWK. So I dared to shorten the game by my answer ;-).

Comment: @dodrg I think the OPs posted example led you to misunderstand their needs. Their file is simply TSV and they should have no trouble filling in Fravadonas skeleton.

Comment: Thank you all.  I was able to modify dodrg's code to get something working for myself.  I know it seems simple to you guys, but to give you some context: I spent 45 minutes troubleshooting because I was using ` instead of ' in my modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm to replace the the values is not the problem.
The interesting point is to maintain the fixed width columns.

File:  `dataconvert.awk`

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = "|"
}
{
    if ($7 ~ /+/) {
        len = length($4)
        $4 = $3
        gsub(/\s+/, "", $4)
        $4 = substr((" " ($4 + 1) "                       "), 0, len)
    } else {
        if ($7 ~ /-/) {
            len = length($3)
            $3 = $4
            gsub(/\s+/, "", $3)
            $3 = substr((" " ($3 - 1) "                       "), 0, len)
        }
    } 
    print
}
```

Mark the as executable by `chmod +x dataconvert.awk` an you can start it directly calling `./dataconvert.awk`

In this solution the width of the column's content is stored, the result filled with a save amount of spaces and finally cropped to the stored length.

If the dataset really has no exceptions in providing the values `+` or `-` at column 6, then the second `if` clause can be omitted. At huge datasets this can save some time.

As the dataset starts with a field delimiter the first column is always empty but exists. So the column count has to be `+1` to the intuitive way to count.

Comment: Regarding "The interesting point is to maintain the fixed width columns." - it would be but the OP doesn't have fixed width columns they have tab-separated values (TSV). Their provided sample input/output that includes `|`s and appears to be fixed width fields is unnecessarily confusing even though they said "no | present in actual data".

Comment: Ed, I thought this would be a source of confusion but I couldn't find a way to copy-paste my data as code while maintaining column spacing.  I had to use a markdown table converter and copy-paste from there, but it included the "|".

Comment: Aha, ok, Pating tabs in code works if you enclose your code by ```  (three accent grave) as markdown code assignement. The code would have been even easier. But like this you really had your exercise to convert it to your needs. Starting somewhat like a script kiddie is a good point to get into the coding. -- Hopefully all parties are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted dodrg's response to work with my data structure. I've accepted their answer but wanted to post this response for anyone who might come upon this in the future.

```
awk ' BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
{
  if ($6 == "+") {
    $2 = $2
    $3 = $2 + 1
  } else {
    if ($6 == "-") {
      $2 = $3 - 1
      $3 = $3
    }
  } 
  print
}'  filein.tsv > fileout.tsv
```

Comment: **1)** The `$2 = $2` and `$3 = $3` are doing nothing useful, just remove those statements. **2)** `else { if ($6 == "-") { $2 = $3 - 1} }` can just be `else if ($6 == "-") { $2 = $3 - 1 }`. **3)** Unless `$6` can have some value you haven't told us about that's neither `+` nor `-`, `else if ($6 == "-") { $2 = $3 - 1 }` can just be `else { $2 = $3 - 1 }`.

Comment: `awk -v OFS='\t' '{if ($6=="+") $3=$2+1; else $2=$3-1} 1' file` is all you actually need.